# DB2: Insert into a column of data type st_Geometry, from a column of varchar datatype? 

Tags: sql, db2, geospatial

Im trying to copy over data from one table to another in the same db2 database, using this command:

```
INSERT INTO SCH.TAB1 (SOMEPK, GEOM)
SELECT SOMEPK, db2gse.ST_Geometry(GEOM) FROM SCH.TAB2
```

The 2 tables are identical except that TAB2 GEOM column is of st_geometry data type while the same column in TAB1 is VAR-CHAR however I want to convert the data in the `GEOM` column from text to `st_geometry` format when I'm copying across, however I get the following error:

```
 SQL0408N  A value is not compatible with the data type of its assignment target. Target name is "GEOM                                                           ".

Explanation: 

The data type of the value to be assigned to the column, parameter, SQL
variable, or transition variable by the SQL statement is incompatible
with the declared data type of the assignment target.

The statement cannot be processed.

User response: 

Examine the statement and possibly the target table or view to determine
the target data type. Ensure the variable, expression, or literal value
assigned has the proper data type for the assignment target.

For a user-defined structured type, also consider the parameter of the
TO SQL transform function defined in the transform group for the
statement as an assignment target.

sqlcode: -408
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for an older version of DB2 but it looks like it might work. The [ST_GeomFromText function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/opt/rsbp4080.htm).

See also [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/csbp4195.html).